# Get the list of resource files copied using maven in a text file or xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is there clean way to get the list of resource file names copied by the maven build from the project resources directory in a text file / xml . This file could be placed in the root of output resources folder.

For e.g

when maven say,

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @   sample-project ---

[debug] execute contextualize

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] Copying 100 resources
```

I need these 100 resource names in an text file in the result jar file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would very much like to know the answer because I need the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the plugin, so there's no out-of-the-box solution.

You'll need to write your own plugin to do this... just checkout the current [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/source-repository.html) and modify it as needed. Looking at the code, I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that you just need to add a bit of code in ResourcesMojo to capture the list of files that will be copied.

There are a few (maybe cheaper) alternatives such as using an ANT task to execute a plain ls/dir and put the output of that in a file.